# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector.pair

Tags: maven, jax-rs, apache-drill

I am trying to wrok with JAX RS service. I have added few dependencies in my pom .xml. Here is the pom.

```
    <properties>
    <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
        <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
        <artifactId>drill-jdbc-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

when i add this dependency `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
            <artifactId>drill-jdbc-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>`
it fails with elow mentioned exception. I need the above mentioned dependecy for apache drill. On removing and running it works smooth.

The excpetion i am getting is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.AnnotationIntrospector.pair(Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/AnnotationIn
trospector;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/AnnotationIntrospector;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/AnnotationIntrospector;
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:648)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:500)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291).
```

Can some one please help as in why on adding the particular dependency it fails with the above exception.

tried running mvn dependency tree to check the conflict in jars.

---

Building JAXRS-JSON Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

 --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ JAXRS-JSON ---
 com.java.codegeeks.example:JAXRS-JSON:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
 |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
 +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.19:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
 |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
 |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
 |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
 |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2:compile
 |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
 |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile
 |     \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
 +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19:compile
 +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
 \- org.apache.drill.exec:drill-jdbc-all:jar:1.1.0:compile
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Most likely `drill-jdbc-all` pulls in Jackson dependencies that conflict `jersey-json` and the version it pulls in. Run [mvn dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) to see if that's the case. If it is, you can try to [exclude](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)  one of the set of transitives

Comment: @peeskillet: thank you for the advice.tried that. couldnt see any issue. see edit.. added the output

Comment: I have never used drill (nor know what it is). Looking at the tag wiki, it looks like it has interaction with Mongo. Since it's an "all" jar, is it possible it repackage Jackson into it's uber jar. Did you check to see if there are any Jackson packages in that jar? I'm just making guesses. Doesn't really make sense why it work without it and fails with it unless it causes conflict with Jackson

Comment: You could alternatively go with Jackson 2. Get rid of `jersey-json`. Add [this dependency](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers), and add this package `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` to your Jersey config to scan the package. You can separate it with a comma from your package

Comment: @peeskillet had already done that. it worked with that. I basically had issue with converting Maps to JSON, which jersey jars did it smoothly, i did not know a way to achieve the same with jackson 2. so wanted to be with jersey.

Comment: Did you post a question about it here? I don't see why Jackson 1 would be be able to handle it and not Jackson 2. Maps are inherently pretty similar to JSON, as they are both key/value pairs. Jackson should have no problem handling Maps, though it might depend on the complexity. If you post a question, I can have a look at it, or maybe someone else can answer it.

Comment: @peeskillet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682042/need-a-way-to-generate-json-from-listmapstring-string-in-jax-rs-service-jack

Answer (score 0):

drill contains too many packages inside it and it collides with other jars in app. I too encountered similar problem but with com.google.common.collect and org.apache.zookeeper packages of drill jar. In my case the version drill is using for these packages are older and so, I just removed those.

```
zip -d drill-jdbc-all-1.1.0.jar com/google/common/collect/*
zip -d drill-jdbc-all-1.1.0.jar org/apache/zookeeper/*
```

Now it is working fine. I am not sure how to handle all these using maven only and so opted to delete. It would be better if maven can handle that.