# Need a way to generate JSON from List<Map<String,String> in JAX RS service. jackson2

Tags: java, json, maven, jax-rs

I have the following in my POM.xml
**Updated complete pom**:

```
<dependencies>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency> -->



            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
                <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
                <artifactId>drill-jdbc-all</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>


        </dependencies>
```

I wanted to generate an JSON from `List<Map<String,String>>`. I always end up having `MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.LinkedHashMap, genericType=jav a.util.Map<String,String>`

I even tried with simple map

```
@GET
      @Path("/test")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public Map<String, String> getMap() {
          Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          map.put("some key", "some value");
          return map;
      }
```

even this produces the same error message.

**UPDATED EXCEPTION STACK TRACE**:

```
Jul 29, 2015 9:23:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CustomerDataService] in context with path [/CustomerDataService] threw exception 
[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.Jackson
JaxbJsonProvider.isWriteable(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljavax/ws/rs/cor
e/MediaType;)Z] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.isWriteable(Ljava/lang/Class;Lja
va/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MediaType;)Z
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.isWriteable(MessageBodyFactory.java:1158)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.WriterModel.isWriteable(WriterModel.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:798)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:756)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterc
eptorExecutor.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInter
ceptor.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOXy doesn't handle maps well as it uses JAXB under the hood, and JAXB sucks with Maps. Use Jackson instead. Get rid of the MOXy dependency. MOXy is the default, so if it is on the classpath, it will be used over all others. Once you take it out, Jackson will be used.

---

#### UPDATE

So the `drill-jdbc-all` actually repackages both Jackson 1.x *and* Jackson 2.x. You can exclude them from the `jersey-media-json-jackson` depedency, since drill already includes them.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        </exclusion> 
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

---

#### UPDATE 2

I guess the above still doesn't work. One way I *was* able to get to work is adding `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` (you also need to take out jersey-media-json-jackson and the jersey-media-moxy).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.drill.exec</groupId>
    <artifactId>drill-jdbc-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The key to this is that it *must* be declared before the `apache-jdbc-drill`. Yea it seems more of a work around that a solution. But the fact that drill packages the dependency is a problem. When Jersey scans, it will will add ours first, and ignore drill's.

You then need to add the provider to your Jersey config

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

I mean I haven't tested this 10,000, but for the 10 to 20 times I did tested, the ordering of the dependencies was the deciding factor for whether or not it would work. Again, like I said, seems like a work-around.

And the add it to the Jersey config

Comment: agreed, but there is certain conflict with the jackson jars with Apache drill dependency and it throws [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json. it seems adding moxy overrides, as you pointed out

Comment: In your previous question, you are using Jackson 1.x. Jackson 1.x, and 2.x are two different animals and they don't conflict with each other. You can use 2 and whatever dependency uses 1.x can use 1.x. And AbstractMethodError is not the same error as NoSuchMethodError as your other question is about. Can you post the actual exception

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem with only the two (jersey-servlet and jersey-jackson) dependencies you have shown? If not, are you able to reproduce it with just the two and the extra drill? If not, I'm not sure how much I can say without being able to reproduce it. I'm 100% positive only the two will not cause the problem, unless you are running in a container that already has Jackson 2.x

Comment: i have updated the complete pom.xml. i have only the dependecies mentioned. when i comment out moxy i recev the exception.

Comment: What server are you running in?

Comment: Spring Tool suite integrated server

Comment: So I actually just downloaded the dependencies, and drill does repackage Jackson **both** Jackson 1.x _and_ Jackson 2.x. _oddd_. Thats's why it failed even when you tried to use Jackson 1.x. I guess drill needs them. You can exclude Jackson from the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency. See the [pom for jersey-media-json-jackson](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.19/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.19.pom). If you know how to exclude transitives, just exclude the three jackson ones you see in pom I linked to

Comment: just to coinfirm. exclude <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId> from org.glassfish.jersey.media.. ?

Comment: See my edit. If that still doesn't work, then take out the whole `jersey-media-json-jackson` and in your Jersey config add the package `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json` as a package to scan.

Comment: Yea I was able to reproduce the same problem. See my second edit

Comment: This resolved the error, but should it not resolve Map on its own. i got SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=java.util
.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>.

Comment: I just tested it, and it works fine for me. `List<Map<...>>` works fine also. Does it work with other normal types? Maybe you didn't configure it right.

Comment: thanks a lot. finally got it to work. thanks for all the effort you put in.. and bearing with me. :) even though u say its a workaround kind of.. but then definitely works.. will explore more around it.. thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize collections and maps. Create a container class.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Container {
    public Map<String, String> data;
}

public Container getMap() {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map.put("some key", "some value");

      // wrap content int container object
      Container container = new Container();
      container.data = map;
      return container ;
}
```

The reason for this issue is, that XML always has to have a single root element.